# ABC notation : how to draw the "piano brace" at the left of the grand staff?

Tags: abc-notation

Good morning-

I have scoured the documentation for EasyABC but can't find how to draw the brace at the left of the grand staff, to couple the two piano parts.

[image]

Can anyone advise please? (I'm assuming it can do it....)

(I have EasyABC version 1.3.8.6, which is the one currently on Sourceforge, as pointed to from abcnotation.com.)

EDIT: I changed the title from "EasyABC" to "ABC notation", having realised the question wasn't limited to EasyABC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the [relevant passage](https://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1#voice_grouping) from the ABC Standard:

> 11.1 Voice grouping
>
> VOLATILE: This section is under review as part of the general discussion about multiple voices for abc 2.2. See also the section 11 disclaimer.
>
> Basic syntax:
>
> %%score   ...
>
> The score directive specifies which voices should be printed in the score and how they should be grouped on the staves.
>
> ...
>
> If voice groups are enclosed by curly braces {}, the corresponding staves will be connected by a big curly brace printed in front of the staves. Together they form a voice block. This format is used especially for typesetting keyboard music.
>
> Example:
>
> %%score Solo  [(S A) (T B)]  {RH | (LH1 LH2)}

---

The following code gives the pictured result on the EasyABC 1.3.8 (latest Mac version as of this post) and the [ABCjs test editor](https://www.abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html).

```
X: 1
T: Bracket Test
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: Emin
%%score {V1 V2}
[V:V1] A B c |
[V:V2] D E F |
```

[image: Two staves, bracketed]

Comment: Since it's piano music, you'll probably want to add a vertical line, i.e. `%%score {V1|V2}`, so that the barlines between the staves connect (only noticeable for examples with more than one measure).